# MS Access year to date numbers by month

Tags: ms-access

I have a query in an Access database which returns the results below:

```
MthName 2010
Jan £4.51
Feb £10.20
Mar £17.51
Apr £22.86
May £28.82
Jun £33.30
Jul £37.96
Aug £42.52
Sep £47.88
Oct £54.25
Nov £60.52
Dec £65.80
```

That is fine but these are year to date numbers and I would like to create a query that could give me the actual month numbers instead.

Taking the above sample the Jan number is clearly £4.51 but the Feb number is

(£10.2-£4.51)= £5.70

I have tried using something like DLOOKUP but it seems that would be really slow and wasn't working correctly.

This can be achieved very easily in Excel but I was hoping to find a query for future use.

Thanks

Comment: Could you show what you have? I think in Access `DLOOKUP` is pretty much your only option here.

Comment: The MTH field returns as a number so I created a mapping table to get it back to MthName. It also included a MthSub field where I adjusted the months so for Jan I had MthSub 0 and Feb 1 etc.

Comment: This is my function to the second table but it returns the results out of sync Test: DLookUp("SumOfIncome","Brokerage_Budget_Historical_2","MthSub=" & [MTH])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using Dlookup as much as you can.

if it is possible to add column [mntNum] with SEQUENCE number of month :

```
mtnNum MthName 2010
01 Jan £4.51
02 Feb £10.20
03 Mar £17.51
04 Apr £22.86
05 May £28.82
06 Jun £33.30
07 Jul £37.96
08 Aug £42.52
09 Sep £47.88
10 Oct £54.25
11 Nov £60.52
12 Dec £65.80
```

Query

```
SELECT table.mntNum, table.mntName, table.[2010], [2010]-nz((SELECT [prev].[2010] FROM [table] as [prev] where [prev].[mntNum]=[table].[mntNum]-1),0) AS JUST_THIS_MONTH
FROM [table];
```

UPD:
Result of this query

```
mntNum  mntName 2010    JUST_THIS_MONTH
1   Jan 4.51    4.51
2   Feb 10.2    5.69
3   Mar 17.51   7.31
4   apr 22.86   5.35
5   may 28.82   5.96
6   jun 33.3    4.48
7   jul 37.96   4.66
8   Aug 42.52   4.56
9   Sep 47.88   5.36
10  Oct 54.25   6.37
11  Nov 60.52   6.27
12  Dec 65.8    5.27999999999999
```

Comment: Think you have misunderstood what the OP means by "*actual month numbers*" - see the example.

Comment: added output of query, and claryfications about [mntNum]

Comment: Thanks for that took a while to get it working because you had mtnNum in the top table and then mntNum in the query. Did get it working though and it's much better than the DLOOKUP.